# Can a Django ModelForm save multiple new models on a single submit?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am learning Django and building a website to save and display cafeteria food offerings. I have a Model Meal and another FoodItem, where multiple FoodItems are children of a Meal.

```
    class Meal(models.Model):

        date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)


        BFAST = 0
        LUNCH = 1
        DIN = 2
        MEAL_TIME_CHOICES = [
            (BFAST, 'Breakfast'),
            (LUNCH, 'Lunch'),
            (DIN, 'Dinner'),
        ]

        meal_time = models.IntegerField(
            choices = MEAL_TIME_CHOICES,
            default = MEAL_TIME_CHOICES[0]
        )


    class FoodItem(models.Model):
        meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

I'd like to create a ModelForm that has multiple textinputs for FoodItems so that multiple foods can be saved and associated with the same meal on a single submission of the form.

My attempt right now only allows me to submit a single food item at a time.

```
class FoodItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FoodItem
        fields = ('name',)
```

Any assistance in doing this the correct way would be much appreciated!

Comment: I really don't get it what you want to achieve i guess you want to select multiple food item name in food item name field right or please be more specific becuase your question and desciription both seems off from each other

Comment: Check out model formsets and specifically, `modelformset_factory`

Comment: Django forms provides a forms.MultipleChoiceField() for us. You can also create those choices dynamically. There are a lot of posts in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an app named `menu`:

```
|menu
├───migrations
|       ...
├───templates
│       detail.html
│       list.html
│   __init__.py
│   admin.py
│   apps.py
│   forms.py
│   models.py
│   tests.py
│   urls.py
│   views.py
|project <--- the name of your "project"
│   asgi.py
│   settings.py
│   urls.py
│   wsgi.py
│   __init__.py
│templates <--- not used
│db.sqlite3
│manage.py
```

Add the `menu` app to installed apps:

**project/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'menu.apps.MenuConfig',
]
```

**project/urls.py** (project-level)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('menu.urls')),
]
```

**menu/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import list_view, detail_view

app_name = 'menu'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', list_view, name='list'),
    path('<pk>/', detail_view, name='detail'),
]
```

**menu/models.py**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models


class Meal(models.Model):

    BFAST = 0
    LUNCH = 1
    DIN = 2

    MEAL_TIME_CHOICES = [
        (BFAST, 'Breakfast'),
        (LUNCH, 'Lunch'),
        (DIN, 'Dinner'),
    ]

    meal_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    meal_time = models.IntegerField(choices=MEAL_TIME_CHOICES,default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.meal_name


class FoodItem(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_item = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_item
```

Make sure you `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

**menu/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from .models import Meal, FoodItem


MealFormset = modelformset_factory(FoodItem, fields=('food_item',),
                                   extra=5, can_delete=True)
```

**menu/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Meal, FoodItem


class MealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class FoodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Meal, MealAdmin)
admin.site.register(FoodItem, MealAdmin)
```

**menu/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import MealFormset
from .models import Meal


def list_view(request):
    context = {
        'objects': Meal.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'list.html', context=context)

def detail_view(request, pk):
    instance = Meal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    formset = MealFormset(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'object': instance,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if formset.is_valid():
            food_items = formset.save(commit=False)
            if formset.deleted_forms:
                for obj in formset.deleted_forms:
                    obj.instance.delete()
            for food_item in food_items:
                food_item.meal = instance
                food_item.save()
            return redirect('menu:list')

    return render(request, 'detail.html', context=context)
```

**menu/templates/list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="margin: auto; width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px;">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin Panel</a>
    <h1>Meals</h1>
    {% for meal in objects %}
    <div>
      <a href="{% url 'menu:detail' meal.pk %}">{{ meal }}</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**menu/templates/detail.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Food Items</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="margin: auto; width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px;">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      {% for field in formset %}
        <div style="padding: 5px 40px;">{{ field }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Might not be *exactly* what you want but illustrates some key concepts (I think).